# How to model/generate Java 8 Optional attributes with Eclipse EMF

Tags: emf, acceleo, ecore

I want to model a class with a field of type `Optional<String>` but can't find a `EOptional` `EType` or equivalents options to maker the attribute optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `EOptional` in EMF. As you are probably writing your own Acceleo generator (from what I understand), you can deal with `EAttribute/EOperation` cardinality. If the `lowerBound` is `0`, it could means that the field is optional and generate the code as such.

Another solution would be to create your own `Optional` `EDataType` with the right `instanceClassName` like EMF 'external types' (see [here](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.9.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/package-summary.html) for some details)